# SQL Exists or IN,

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I have 3 tables,

- `TCorporateSponsors` - 5 Sponsors
  (intCorporateSponsorID, strCompanyName, strFirstName, strLastName)
- `TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypes`
  (intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID, intEventID, intCorporateSponsorshipTypeID, monTypeCost)
- `TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeCorporateSponsors`
  (intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeCorporateSponsorID, intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID, intCorporateSponsorID)

The goal is to return all sponsors even if they did not donate. I have one corporate sponsor that did not donate the 5th one.

This code below returns the 4 sponsors and total donations but the 5th sponsor is left out. How would I ensure all 5 are displayed?

```sql
SELECT 
    TC.intCorporateSponsorID AS CorporateSponsorID, 
    TC.strCompanyName, 
    SUM(TECST.monTypeCost) AS TotalAmountSponsoredToDate
FROM 
    TCorporateSponsors AS TC  
JOIN 
    TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeCorporateSponsors AS TECSTCS
        ON TC.intCorporateSponsorID = TECSTCS.intCorporateSponsorID
JOIN
    TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypes AS TECST 
        ON TECST.intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID = TECSTCS.intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID
WHERE 
    TC.intCorporateSponsorID IN (1,2,3,4,5) -- There are a total of 5 Sponsors, number 5 did not donate. When I run only the 4 show up. 
GROUP BY TC.intCorporateSponsorID, TC.strCompanyName
```

Other ideas I'm not sure how to execute:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TCorporateSponsors
              WHERE TCorporateSponsors.intCorporateSponsorID BETWEEN 1 and 5)
```

Comment: which dbms are you using (MySql; Postresql; sqlite; MS sql server, ...)? they have often their own "flavor" of sql language, that may impact the answer.

Comment: ok, added the tag. FYI, the DBMS (database system) is "MS SQL Server", Management Studio is basically  just some additional tool that you use to interact in a user friendly (or developer-friendly) way with the database server.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN to get all rows from first table even if there are no matches in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` here.

Either use it on both joins, or better: nest an `INNER JOIN` inside the `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
SELECT 
    TC.intCorporateSponsorID AS CorporateSponsorID, 
    TC.strCompanyName, 
    SUM(TECST.monTypeCost) AS TotalAmountSponsoredToDate
FROM 
    TCorporateSponsors AS TC  
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeCorporateSponsors AS TECSTCS
    INNER JOIN
        TEventCorporateSponsorshipTypes AS TECST 
        ON TECST.intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID = TECSTCS.intEventCorporateSponsorshipTypeID
    ) ON TC.intCorporateSponsorID = TECSTCS.intCorporateSponsorID
GROUP BY
    TC.intCorporateSponsorID,
    TC.strCompanyName;
```

Note that the parenthesis `()` are optional, the key is nesting the `ON` clauses.